# Elasticsearch returns old sql results

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch

I have built an index that pulls data from a table in SQL server

```
{
    "type":"jdbc",
    "jdbc": 
    {
        "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://[my_ip];databaseName=mega",
        "user":"sa","password":"******",
        "sql":"SELECT [OrderID],[CustomerName],[UserFullName],[Status]  FROM [Orders_Table]",
        "poll":"5s",
        "index": "mega",
        "type": "orders_search",
        "schedule" : "0 0-59 0-23 ? * *"
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am receiving unrelevant query results.

**For example**:  [**5220668**] is the row key that should be returned only once as contained in the database.

```
{

    "from" : 0, "size" : 5,
    "query": { 
        "multi_match": {
           "query": "5220668", 
           "fields": [ "_all" ]
        }
    } 
}
```

**The result**: something is wrong with the result.
I am expecting to see only one hit as presented in the database. instead the query retrieve the whole life circle of the row statuses

```
{
   "took": 12,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "mega",
            "_type": "handledorders_search",
            "_id": "AU3OlBkh6JN7xIrOkzjm",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "Status": "NEW",
               "Date": "2015-06-07T03:00:12.110Z",
               "UserFullName": "my name",
               "CustomerName": "cust name",
               "OrderID": 5220668
            },
            "sort": [
               1433646012110
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "mega",
            "_type": "handledorders_search",
            "_id": "AU3Ok0E-6JN7xIrOkvpF",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "Status": "NEW",
               "Date": "2015-06-07T03:00:12.110Z",
               "UserFullName": "my name",
               "CustomerName": "cust name",
               "OrderID": 5220668
            },
            "sort": [
               1433646012110
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "mega",
            "_type": "handledorders_search",
            "_id": "AU3Ole0-6JN7xIrOk7Yo",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "Status": "FIX",
               "Date": "2015-06-07T03:00:12.110Z",
               "UserFullName": "my name",
               "CustomerName": "cust name",
               "OrderID": 5220668
            },
            "sort": [
               1433646012110
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "mega",
            "_type": "handledorders_search",
            "_id": "AU3OlQL86JN7xIrOk3eH",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "Status": "CLOSE",
               "Date": "2015-06-07T03:00:12.110Z",
               "UserFullName": "my name",
               "CustomerName": "cust name",
               "ExternalOrderID": 5220668
            },
            "sort": [
               1433646012110
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Different statuses for the same order id. And what's wrong with that?

Comment: It seems you have the same order with the same status twice, are you sure the query has been executed just once? Also in the data the OrderId becomes an ExternalOrderId in the last record. I would check the data first and check the amount of times the query is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are using the _river plugin or something similar, and are relying on Elasticsearch polling MSSQL data.

The tricky part is that when the document changes, Elasticsearch does not know if it needs to update the document or create a new one. You know the documents are the same, but ES does not. You need to tell ES that the documents are the same.

There are two different ways. The first one is to tell ES that a specific field is the unique identifier. You would need to create a mapping with something similar to

```
{
    "mega" : {
        "_id" : {
            "path" : "OrderId"
        }
    }
}
```

This method has been deprecated since 1.5.0

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html

The other possibility is the simplest one and it is to map OrderId to _id in the SQL initialization.

More information http://blog.pluralsight.com/elasticsearch-and-sql-server

> The way a select statement with an alias that tells SQL Server to
>   return the primary key field “ID” as “_id”. This is the default key
>   convention that Elasticsearch uses for all documents. It’s important
>   to keep this nomenclature when selecting your data so that
>   Elasticsearch knows to update  a document and not create a new one
>   each time it polls